# Convert Git subdirectories into submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-cherry-pick

Using Windows for development, Debian for servers and repos, Git Extensions as Git client.

I have the following repos:

REPO1:

```
ROOT_OF_SITE1/
```

REPO2:

```
ROOT/
    /SITE1/
    /SITE2/
    /SITE3/
```

SITE2 and SITE1 share the same code base, just SITE1 is a few commits ahead, but since the path is different can not cherry pick commits from SITE1 from REPO1 to SITE1 in REPO2.

I suppose one of the solutions is to convert SITE2 subdirectory to Git submodule, so then I could cherry pick commits from SITE1.

However each time I use git submodules, I'm facing problems in Git Extensions.

Unfortunately the Git Extensions Git client does not support subtree at this time.

Comment: Show how you use submodules

Comment: How to show? I just remember, that I had problems with Git Extensions and submodules together.

Comment: You ran some commands, right? What were they?

Comment: Usually I used Git Extensions GUI to create submodules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use one repo with SITE1 and I would split the rest of sites using  `git subtree`. You can divide your repo in different branches, keeping several modules organized with a quite clean tree:

```
git subtree split --prefix=site2 -b site2
```

Check [this post](https://tsh.io/blog/git-subtree-or-how-i-stopped-worrying-and-learned-to-love-external-dependencies/) for further information. You can then build the tree back leaving a really nice git history.

Comment: Unfortunately Git Extensions git client does not support subtree at this time.

Comment: You can use [Git bash](https://gitforwindows.org/) or similar and the command line

Comment: I did read the subtree article and I found it very useful: https://tsh.io/blog/git-subtree-or-how-i-stopped-worrying-and-learned-to-love-external-dependencies/ I will try subtree from command line.

Comment: I did not try myself in-depth but people says is awesome and they recommend the use of git subtree instead of git submodule